# Как сделать список в словаре в JS

Tags: javascript, list, словари

Есть объекты:

```
{1:'dffd'},{2:'dfasdasdfd'},{1:'dasdffd'},{3:'asddffd'}
```

Как из них сделать список внутри словаря, например:

```
{
    1:['dffd','dasdffd'],
    2:['dfasdasdfd'],
    3:['asddffd']
}
```

Comment: Если объекты лежат в массиве, то циклом обходить все элементы и добавлять в новый объект по ключам. Если объекты в разных переменных, то надо их как то объединить или вручную прописывать.

Comment: @Swad Как добавить по ключу? объекты получаю по очереди но с параметром ключ значение

Comment: Вопросы должны также содержать попытки автора решить задачу, без них (попыток), вопрос будет являться учебным заданием. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Answer (score -1):

```js
let test = [{1:'dffd'},{2:'dfasdasdfd'},{1:'dasdffd'},{3:'asddffd'}];
let result = {};
test.forEach((elem, index) => {  
    let key = Object.keys(elem)[0];
    if (!result[key]) result[key] = [];
    result[key].push(elem[key])
})

console.log(result);
```